# Log File not appending Properly

Tags: logging, log4j

In my application am using...log4j File Appender Not working Properly...
My log file size i kept 3000kB, after that new Log File is not Creating and it overided the Existing log file...

Its not creating loggy.log, loggy.log1,loggy.log2....

Its overriding in loggy.log when it reaches 3000KB...

what would be the Problem...

heres my log4j.properties

```
log4j.watch=true
log4j.readtime=30000

log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, applicationlogging
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, strutslogging


log4j.category.applicationlogging = DEBUG, applicationlogging


##set logging level for HttpClient
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=DEBUG
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=OFF
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=OFF
log4j.additivity.applicationlogging = false
log4j.additivity.strutslogging = false

# inven.log
log4j.appender.applicationlogging=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.applicationlogging.File=C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat6.0/webapps/Project/WEB-INF/logs/loggy.log
log4j.appender.applicationlogging.File=E:/Final/Project/WebContent/WEB-INF/logs/loggy.log
#og4j.appender.applicationlogging.File=C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/Project/WEB-INF/logs/loggy.log
log4j.appender.applicationlogging.MaxFileSize=3000KB
log4j.appender.applicationlogging.MaxBackupIndex=50
log4j.appender.applicationlogging.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.applicationlogging.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
   log4j.appender.applicationlogging.Append=true
```